# I have to design a chess game so that except horse no other piece should jump other piece I need an algorithm to do it

Tags: java, chess

I have read a tutorial from here [a link](http://echoworld.in/simple-chess-getting-the-layout-ready/)! which gives me a basic layout of pieces but now my pieces jumps over other pieces can I know how to check that whether there is some intermediate coins between source and destination square .

Comment: Do you have some code to refer to? Otherwise it's hard to answer your question

Comment: It is called a knight not a horse

Answer (score 8):

As a simple example, say you have an 8x8 matrix representing the chess board. While you can store objects (and get a nice OO design pattern, having all your pieces extend `ChessPiece`, I'm just going to assume they're all `int`s for now).

```
public class Board
  // this is the actual representation of the board
  private int[][] board = new int[8][8];

  // define some useful constants
  public static final int EMPTY = 0;
  public static final int PAWN = 1;
  public static final int HORSEY = 2;
  // ...

  public Board() {
    initializeBoard();
  }

  public int getPiece(int row, int column) {
    return board[row][column];
  }

  private void initializeBoard() {
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        board[row][col] = EMPTY;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that we have a basic representation of the board and pieces (leaving it up to you to set the actual initial configuration of the pieces), how do we determine where we can move? Well, for now, stick to the simple brute force approach. You know how to loop through the entire board to find the row/column of a piece, so say you find that a knight is at `row=3`, `column=5` which I'll write as `(3,5)`. Then since a knight can move either 1 square horizontally and 2 vertically, or 2 horizontally and 1 vertically, we see that it can possibly move to the following:

- (1,6)
- (1,4)
- (5,6)
- (5,4)
- (2,7)
- (2,3)
- (4,7)
- (4,3)
- In general: (row ± 1, col ± 2), (row ± 2, col ± 1)

So now you have all the components for setting up a board, finding where specific pieces are located, and determining both where they can move and what is located at those spaces.

A few more pieces are needed and then you have everything:

- **Determine what's in the way:**
  Say I try to move a queen from (1,1) to (8,8). You need to determine that the path it would take is through (2,2), (3,3), ... and check each of those squares. This will be different for each piece, but follows the same general approach:

  1. is the piece allowed to move in that path
  2. what squares does that path move through?
  3. are there any pieces in those squares?
- **Actually move the pieces:**
  Here you need to update the internal board representation to change the previous square to empty and the new square to have the piece.
- **Capturing pieces:**
  Implement the rules for capturing a piece (basically the same as moving a piece), and keeping track of which pieces have been captured.
- **Gameplay:**
  If you want to make it playable, you'll need to represent the players, who's turn it is, and generate a simple UI.
- **Edge cases:**
  Make sure not to run off the edge of the board in your algorithms. (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Since generate a game from scratch is very difficult, I'd suggest that you start slowly. Implement the board representation, and check out a testing library like JUnit so that you can use tests as the interface until you have one. For example, write tests to ensure that a piece can move from one square to another given a specific board configuration, then implement that functionality, and have a high confidence when the test passes that your code does what you think it should.